# How to use Coldfusion json data to match textbox input and display value in second textbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, coldfusion

I have a form that has a textbox called txtMaterial which has a class of .txtmaterial and another textbox which is called txtDescription.
When the user enters a material number the ajax query runs and checks to see if there is a match, if there is a match, then txtDescription textbox is populated with the description.

I have the following function to search for materials and return data in a Coldfusion JSON format:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $("#frmCreateClaimLine tbody").on("change", ".txtmaterial", function(){

        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var material = row.find("input.txtmaterial").val();


          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"index.cfm?action=material.search_materials",
            cache: false,
            datatype: 'json',
            data:{
                material_id: material
            },
            success:function(result){
             console.log(result);
            }});

    });
```

The result of console.log is:

{"ROWCOUNT":1,"COLUMNS":["TC_MATERIAL","TC_DESCRIPTION","TC_LANGUAGE"],"DATA":{"TC_MATERIAL":["000000000000061234"],"TC_DESCRIPTION":["THERMOMETER"],"TC_LANGUAGE":["E"]}}

EDIT:
here is my query:

```
<cfquery name="qryGetMaterials" datasource="FR01CLDB" maxrows="100">
    SELECT
        TC_MATERIAL,
        TC_DESCRIPTION,
        TC_LANGUAGE
    FROM
        TBYE53_CSP_MATRL_LANGUAGE_DIM
    WHERE
        UPPER(TC_MATERIAL) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Trim(UCase(material_id))#">
    AND
        TC_LANGUAGE = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#UserLanguage#">
</cfquery>

<cfset theJSON = SerializeJSON(qryGetMaterials,true)>
```

```
<cfoutput>#theJSON#</cfoutput>
```

What I cant figure out is how to check to see if the value of the txtMaterial matches a value in the returned JSON data and display the description in the description field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you do a `JSON.parse(result)` will make the result an object which will be easier to manipulate. But on the coldfusion side it's a bit easier if you use `serializejson()` and change the second value to true I believe. It makes it a bit easier to work with. Then you will have an JS object that is much like a CF Query object. You can then loop through the rows in javascript. http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_s_03.html

Comment: Hi, I have already serialized the output using serializejson().

Comment: Edit: Assuming your query does an *exact* match, you do not need to check values. Simply verify the `ROWCOUNT` is `> 0`. If it is, you know a match was found. Then grab the value from `result.DATA.TC_DESCRIPTION[0]`. Also, you have a typo in the ajax call. It should be: `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Yeah but try `serializeJSON(query,true)` then the object won't the organized the same way and if I remember right make it easier to work with in Javscript.

Comment: @Leeish - Looking at the sample results, I believe they are already doing that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your query does an *exact* match, no need to check values. Simply verify the `ROWCOUNT` is greater than zero. If it is, you know a match was found. Then grab the description in the first row and update your text field

```
    if (result.ROWCOUNT > 0) {
        var descrip = result.DATA.TC_DESCRIPTION[0];
        // ... update text field
    }
```

Also, there is a small typo in the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call. It should be `dataType` (capital "T"), instead of `datatype`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input, i now have this working after fixing typos and using @Leigh's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
success:function(result){
   console.log(result);    
}
```

To this:

```
success:function(result){
  if(material == result.DATA.TC_MATERIAL[0])
  {
    //PUT YOUR CODE HERE
  }
}
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/fwdwL5eh/2/

Comment: If i add this i get the follwoing error: TypeError: result.DATA is undefined

Comment: I added a sample fiddle